# Why does my Discord bot keep repeating when it runs this command?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

This is the code used, there is nothing (I think) that's causing it to repeat, matter of fact I added something so it stops repeating but it didn't do anything at all.

```
client.on('message', e =>{
    if(e.member.roles.cache.has('12345678901')){
        if(!e.content.startsWith(p) || e.author.bot) return;
        console.log('successfully unmuted')
        var ar = e.content.slice(p.length).split(/ +/)
        var cmd = ar.shift().toLowerCase();
    
        if(cmd === 'b'){
            console.log('succesfully banned')
            var member = e.mentions.users.first();
            if(member){
                var membertarget = e.guild.members.cache.get(member.id)
                membertarget.ban();
                var sbbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('GREEN')
                .setTitle('success!')
                .setDescription(`<@${membertarget.user.id}> has been successfully banned!`)
            }else {
                var bbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RED')
                .setTitle('invalid user!')
                .setDescription('ban failed because there was not a valid member mentioned :(')
                e.channel.send({ embeds: [bbed] })
            }
        }
    } else {
        var rolefb = new discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('RED')
.setTitle('failed!')
.setDescription('sorry! you dont have a high enough role to use this command, but this can change!')
        if (e.author.bot) return;
        e.channel.send({embeds: [rolefb]})
    }

    
})
```

This code is supposed to just ban somebody but it keeps repeating itself whenever it fails:

[image: issue]

Code:

```js
client.on('message', e =>{
    if (e.author.bot) return
    if(e.member.roles.cache.has('960191891473829929')){
```

I have edited the code, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Your code in the `message` event listener runs whenever a message is posted in your server so the bot sending the message will also be counted. So all you have to do is add an if statement in the start to check whether the author of the message was a bot:

```js
if (message.author.bot) return
```

Comment: didnt work but thanks

Comment: Why? What error did you get?

Comment: i didnt get any error, it just kept repeating

Comment: or maybe i could be doing it wrong. do i put your snippet right before if(e.member.roles.cache.has('960191891473829929')){

Comment: Yes. It should be before any other if statements

Comment: weird because i put it there and it doesnt work

Comment: Can you show your current code by editing the question?

Comment: client.on('message', e =>{
    if (e.author.bot) return
    if(e.member.roles.cache.has('960191891473829929')){

Comment: It is a little tough trying to read the code this way. Can you edit the question with your current code?

Comment: yes i just edited it

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure why it is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this statement to your code before `if(e.member.roles.cache.has('12345678901')){`

```
if (e.author == client.user) return;
```

Also, change the `if(e.member.roles.cache.has('12345678901')){` to `else if (e.member.roles.cache.has('12345678901')){`.

I would recommend restructuring the entire code and make it into a command handler, though.